# Copy Files from a folder to multiple folders based on the file name in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, copy, azure-data-factory, move

I have a parent folder in ADLS Gen2 called **Source** which has number of subfolders and these subfolders contain the actual data files as shown in in the below example...

***Source: ***

**Folder Name:** 20221212

`A_20221212.txt B_20221212.txt C_20221212.txt`

**Folder Name:** 20221219

`A_20221219.txt B_20221219.txt C_20221219.txt`

**Folder Name:** 20221226

`A_20221226.txt B_20221226.txt C_20221226.txt`

How can I copy files from subfolders to name specific folders (should create a new folder if it does not exist) using Azure Data Factory, please see the example below...

***Target: ***

**Folder Name:** A

`A_20221212.txt A_20221219.txt A_20221226.txt`

**Folder Name:** B

`B_20221212.txt B_20221219.txt B_20221226.txt`

**Folder Name:** C

`C_20221212.txt C_20221219.txt C_20221226.txt`

Really appreciate your and help.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far? also, is folder structure same for all files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the above and got below results.

You can follow the below procedure using Get Meta data activity if you have the folder directories at same level.

This is my source folder structure.

```
data
    20221212
        A_20221212.txt
        B_20221212.txt
        C_20221212.txt`
    20221219
        A_20221219.txt
        B_20221219.txt
        C_20221219.txt
    20221226
        A_20221226.txt
        B_20221226.txt
        C_20221226.txt
```

**Source dataset:**

[image]

Give this to Get Meta data activity and use `ChildItems`.

Then Give the ChildItems array from Get Meta data activity to a ForEach activity. Inside ForEach I have used set variable for storing folder name.

```
@split(item().name,'_')[0]
```

[image]

Now, use copy activity and in source use wild card path like below.

[image]

For sink create dataset parameters and give it copy activity sink like below.

[image]

[image]

**My pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "sourcetxt",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "wildcardFolderPath": "*",
                                        "wildcardFileName": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "sourcetxt",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "targettxts",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "folder_name": {
                                            "value": "@variables('folder_name')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "file_name": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable1",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "folder_name",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@split(item().name,'_')[0]",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "folder_name": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm Rakesh. Thanks for your detailed solution, including JSON file.